# In c# I am doing a development with the SNMP protocol. I am trying to get the header of a table

Tags: c#, snmp, snmpsharpnet

I get the table data, but I need to get the name of the column it belongs to as the "ireasoning mib browser" app does. When I do the "table view" operation, I get the headers. Does anyone know how I can get those headers in C#?

The library I am using is "snmpsharpnet".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's impossible with snmpsharpnet, as the headers only exist in MIB documents which you cannot extract with that library. Special libraries are needed.

Alternatively, if your scope is small and with just a few specific tables, you can hard code their column headers in your own code by reading the related MIB documents yourself.